# Como enviar formulário de site para e-mail

Tags: php, javascript, html5, css3, formulário

Preciso fazer o envio do formulário de um site para e-mail do cliente.

Imagem do formulário:
[image: Imagem do formulário:]
todas as validações estão funcionando corretamente mas quando peço para enviar aparece a mensagem de que o servidor não foi encontrado;
O site já está hospedado em no servidor da hostnet e o e-mail é outlook: mcampelo@outlook.com.br

abaixo o código PHP:

```html
<?php
// Check for empty fields
if(empty($_POST['name'])    ||
   empty($_POST['email'])   ||
   empty($_POST['phone'])   ||
   empty($_POST['message']) ||
   !filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
   {
 echo "No arguments Provided!";
 return false;
   }
 
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email_address = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
 
// Create the email and send the message
$to = 'mcampelo@outlook.com.br'; // Add your email address inbetween the '' replacing yourname@yourdomain.com - This is where the form will send a message to.
$email_subject = "Website Contact Form:  $name";
$email_body = "You have received a new message from your website contact form.\n\n"."Here are the details:\n\nName: $name\n\nEmail: $email_address\n\nPhone: $phone\n\nMessage:\n$message";
$headers = "From: noreply@yourdomain.com\n"; // This is the email address the generated message will be from. We recommend using something like noreply@yourdomain.com.
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address"; 
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
return true;   
?>
```

Abaixo código JavaScript validação:

```
    $(function() {

    $("input,textarea").jqBootstrapValidation({
        preventSubmit: true,
        submitError: function($form, event, errors) {
            // additional error messages or events
        },
        submitSuccess: function($form, event) {
            event.preventDefault(); // prevent default submit behaviour
            // get values from FORM
            var name = $("input#name").val();
            var email = $("input#email").val();
            var phone = $("input#phone").val();
            var message = $("textarea#message").val();
            var firstName = name; // For Success/Failure Message
            // Check for white space in name for Success/Fail message
            if (firstName.indexOf(' ') >= 0) {
                firstName = name.split(' ').slice(0, -1).join(' ');
            }
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://bootstrapseven.com/demos/enhenyero/html/submit.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    name: name,
                    phone: phone,
                    email: email,
                    message: message
                },
                cache: false,
                success: function() {
                    // Success message
                    $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-success'>");
                    $('#success > .alert-success').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;")
                        .append("</button>");
                    $('#success > .alert-success')
                        .append("<strong>Sua menságem foi enviada com sucesso. </strong>");
                    $('#success > .alert-success')
                        .append('</div>');

                    //clear all fields
                    $('#contact-form').trigger("reset");
                },
                error: function() {
                    // Fail message
                    $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-danger'>");
                    $('#success > .alert-danger').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;")
                        .append("</button>");
                    $('#success > .alert-danger').append("<strong>Desculpe " + firstName + ", parece que meu servidor de e-mail não está respondendo. Por favor, tente novamente mais tarde!");
                    $('#success > .alert-danger').append('</div>');
                    //clear all fields
                    $('#contact-form').trigger("reset");
                },
            })
        },
        filter: function() {
            return $(this).is(":visible");
        },
    });

    $("a[data-toggle=\"tab\"]").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).tab("show");
    });
});


/*When clicking on Full hide fail/success boxes */
$('#name').focus(function() {
    $('#success').html('');
});
```

Comment: Qual exatamente a mensagem que aparece? Pode postar um print?

Comment: A mensagem de erro que aparece é a que está no Java Script, na function error //fail message, acho que o JavaScript não está conseguindo acessar o arquivo PHP.

Comment: Tenta exibir no console `console.log()` o que retorna do Ajax para ver. Coloca dentro do bloco de erro.

Comment: Menságem: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://bootstrapseven.com/demos/enhenyero/html/submit.php. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://www.mcampelotopografia.com.br' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: O problema é que a página que vc tah requisitando não está autorizando acesso.

Comment: Se vc tah querendo enviar um email, por que não usa no Ajax a página em PHP que vc postou acima?

Comment: Acho que agora entendi. O PHP acima é o mesmo da URL no Ajax. Mas eu notei que o e-mail no "from" está `noreply@yourdomain.com\n`. Acho que vc deve colocar lá um e-mail válido. Geralmente os provedores só enviam email cujo o domínio do remetente seja o mesmo da hospedagem (Ex.: seu site: www.meusite.com.br. O e-mail deve ser obrigatoriamente @meusite.com.br)

Comment: Sim. Também o Ajax não acessa outros domínios. Dá erro de autorização.

Comment: Ok vou criar um e-mail do provedor e testar novamente

Comment: Só uma outra duvida, qual url devo colocar para o arquivo em PHP

Comment: Ele está no www/submit.php

Comment: no mesmo local da página index.html

Comment: Na URL você cola só o nome do arquivo PHP se estiver na mesma pasta do Ajax.

Comment: Assim: `url: "submit.php",`

Comment: Verifiquei o plano de hospedagem aqui e não suporta PHP =(

Comment: provavelmente este é o motivo do erro, ou estou errado ?

Comment: Uai. A maioria dos servidores suportam PHP, inclusive Windows. Faz um teste: cria um arquivo teste.php com `<?php echo "este servidor suporta PHP" ?>` e tenta abrir. Se aparecer a mensagem acima é pq suporta.

Comment: Pra enviar email pelo site é preciso de algum ambiente de programação, como PHP ou ASP, por exemplo.

Comment: Obrigado, @DavidSamm mas o meu provedor não tem suporte ao PHP vou ter que fazer de outra forma.